# Estimating X based on Y values in neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Let's say I have a trained neural network model, preferably with couple of dense layers. It has learned to estimate Y values based on X values.

Can I somehow use the same trained model and find approximation of X values that result in a specific Y values?

In other words, I have some Y values, I'd like to find out X values which if I feed to the same model, result those Y values.

Comment: It is sometimes possible. The same topic is opened on StackExchange AI: [Can we get the inverse of the function that a neural network represents?
](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/17566/can-we-get-the-inverse-of-the-function-that-a-neural-network-represents)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible given a target value to get a range of values for the features. In classification, this is often called the decision surface or [decision boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_boundary).